# Can't change default limit on Spotify API (Top Artists) - React Native

Tags: reactjs, api, native, spotify

I've tried everything to change this... no idea what's going wrong, it's still just pulling 20 artists back no matter what.

```
const sp = await this.getValidSPObj();
const { id: userId } = await sp.getMe();
const { items: topArtists } = await sp.getMyTopArtists(userId, {limit: 10, offset: 20});
this.props.setData("TopArtists", topArtists);
```

Notes from the API...

```
/**
 * Get the current user’s top artists based on calculated affinity.
 * See [Get a User’s Top Artists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-users-top-artists-and-tracks/) on
 * the Spotify Developer site for more information about the endpoint.
 *
 * @param {Object} options A JSON object with options that can be passed
 * @param {function(Object,Object)} callback An optional callback that receives 2 parameters. The first
 * one is the error object (null if no error), and the second is the value if the request succeeded.
 * @return {Object} Null if a callback is provided, a `Promise` object otherwise
 */
getMyTopArtists(
  options?: Object,
  callback?: ResultsCallback<SpotifyApi.UsersTopArtistsResponse>
): Promise<SpotifyApi.UsersTopArtistsResponse>;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the function `signature` there is no `standalone` parameter for the `userID`, you are passing `userID` as the `first` parameter, actually the `first` parameter is the `options` object!

the docs also refer to that some `functions` don't need the `userID`:
https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js#getting-users-information

> Some functions don't need to receive the user's id as a parameter, and will use the user's information from the access token: <code_example>

p.s.: I believe based on your `access_token` and `scope` it figures out the user.